# Run a regular expression into a new file (or another existing file)

Tags: html, regex, vim, rss, html-parsing

I would like to take some stuff from file A and reformat it to stick into file B using regular expressions.  I am kind of new to vim so this may be a dumb question but I could not find the solution to this anywhere.  I guess I am searching for the wrong phrases.  Anyway, here are the details of what I want to do.  I have a static html page that I would like to have an RSS feed for.  Luckily, this page is mostly links to various news items, so creating the RSS will be pretty easy.

I have the regular expression ready:

```
:%s/^<a href="\(.\{-}\)".title="\(.\{-}\)">\(.\{-}\)<\/a>/<title>\3<\/title>\r<link>\1<\/link>\r<description>\2<\/description>
```

My problem is I do not want to make the changes in the html file that I am searching.  I want the changes to occur in another file, new or existing.  How do I make this happen?  Or is this method completely off.

Oh and by the way, this expression takes something like this in the html file:

```
<a href="http://linktosomesite.com" title="Description of link">Title of Link</a>
```

and turns it into this in the xml file:

```
<title>Title of Link</title>
<link>http://linktosomesite.com</link>
<description>Description of link</description>
```

Bonus: It would be really nice if I can place this within another file, say starting at line 5.

PS: I know this is a vim and regex question but posting it in html and rss because I noticed people have static html to rss questions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to write a transform.  There are many transform tools. You certainly could do it with sed & awk for example. But I think the easiest way would be xslt. (you could use `xsltproc` or `saxon`...)

Here's an example template:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <title><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></title>
    <link><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></link>
    <description><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></description>
</xsl:template>
```

It finds each `a` element, and outputs the results, with the text() node and attributes filled in.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  As I am someone that has never done this before, what xslt processor do you recommend?  Heading over to read documentation on the two you mentioned.  Looking for something that will work on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just copy your file and then use sed/replace on the copied file?

Comment: Thanks, but I have other data in there, and this would copy all of that there as well.  I probably should have mentioned that.  Up vote anyway for something I did not even think about.

Answer (score 2):

Just run your substitution and save as another file:

```
$ vim file.html
:%s/^<a href="\(.\{-}\)".title="\(.\{-}\)">\(.\{-}\)<\/a>/<title>\3<\/title>\r<link>\1<\/link>\r<description>\2<\/description>
:w file.rss
:q
```

That's how I would in any editor, by the way.